# de'morgans law boolean translation discrepency. what am i downg wrong?

Tags: boolean

demorgans law states in this article

https://ryanstutorials.net/boolean-algebra-tutorial/boolean-algebra-laws.php#introduction

that NOT(P & K) = NOT(P) OR NOT(K)

so i did a little testing with 1's and zeros

```
NOT(1 AND 1) = false
NOT(1 AND 0) = false
NOT(0 AND 1) = false
NOT(O AND 0) = true
```

so then i did the second expression

```
NOT(1) OR NOT(O) = TRUE
NOT(0) OR NOT(1) = TRUE
NOT(0) OR NOT(0) = TRUE
NOT(1) OR NOT(1) = FALSE
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this table : 
`P K | Q Q'`
`0 0 | 0 1` 
`0 1 | 0 1` 
`1 0 | 0 1` 
`1 1 | 1 0` 
The `Q` is the `Output` and the `Q'` is the `Output'`, 0=false and 1=true;
So, the first column is obtained doing `P*K` and the second denying `Q`so `P'+K'`.